# NPMLE of a random sample from common df with ties?

Tags: self-study, survival

I'm working on the following question. Could anyone help with how to approach it and where to go with it?

Show that if a random sample X1, ..., Xn is from a common distribution function F where there may be ties among the Xi's, then the empirical distribution function is the NPMLE for F.

I am able to show this when we can assume that there are no ties among the Xi's, but I'm struggling to find an approach when there may be ties. Can someone please help me out?

Comment: It seems that this is a question arising out of a course or textbook or your own independent study. That type of question is welcome on this site, but please add the `self-study` tag to the question and read the [info page](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info). Specify what you've tried for the case with ties so that you can get useful hints to the solution.

Comment: I provided an answer (good hints). But why does this question deserve an upvote, which it has received? That's ridiculous.

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

Use weights based on number of occurrence for data points, rather than all equally weighted, which is what you do when there are no ties.

What happens when you look at Profile Likelihood https://www.stat.tamu.edu/~suhasini/teaching613/profile_likelihood.pdf ?  What can you deduce based on the maximization which is performed?

With these hints, it's a piece of cake, but you still need to do some work.